# Node js - Axios Dependabot Alert Issue

Tags: node.js, axios, nodejs-server, axios-retry, axios-cookiejar-support

Axios Issue -  Hi I am getting the Axios dependabot alert issue. I have updated the Axios versions(1.6.1,1.6.2), still not able to resolve the Axios dependabot issue. Please help me to resolve the issue. Updated the latest version of Axios, the issue was not resolved.

```
[enter image description here][1]

Axios Cross-Site Request Forgery Vulnerability #59
 Open Opened last month on axios (npm) · frontend-dynamic-template/package-lock.json
Upgrade axios to fix 1 Dependabot alert in frontend-dynamic-template/package-lock.json
Upgrade axios to version 1.6.0 or later. For example:

"dependencies": {
  "axios": ">=1.6.0"
}
"devDependencies": {
  "axios": ">=1.6.0"
}

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv2Pr.png
```

Comment: Its for security your can update and merge pull request if Dependabot created.